# Excel Power Query Date Format Issue

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I'm undertaking my first project where I have to analyze temperature/humidity readings from 10 separate data loggers. I have exported the 10 data logger readings to 10 .csv files and I'm trying to use excel power query to reference each of the 10 .csv files to get min/max/average readings in an excel summary file.

All is going great apart from the date column (text type) that is exported in the .csv files.

31:40.0 
41:40.0
51:40.0

That is the format they are given in, which, if I open in excel (and change the format) translates to:

8/22/2017  1:31:40 PM
8/22/2017  1:41:40 PM
8/22/2017  1:51:40 PM

But I'm at a loss as to how to convert this date column in the query editor to something which I can use in my excel summary file. In power query, I've tried changing Data Types and adding custom columns with formula (DateTime.FromText), but it doesn't seem to be working out for me so far.

Has anyone else dealt with this scenario? What steps or topics should I look into in order to solve this problem?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: UPDATE: I can change the date format in the individual .csv files show that a usable date will work, but I've seen projects where we have 150+ loggers so... I'd rather not do that :D

Comment: UPDATE 2: I ended up exporting a .txt file instead of a .csv file from the data logging software and everything is as smooth as butter!